# How can I know remote server's hostname in SFTP?

Tags: load-balancing, sftp

We have 2 remote servers for redundancy and SFTP connection is distributed to these 2 servers by F5 VIP. We connect to the server with `sftp username@xxx.yyy.zzz.www` (`xxx.yyy.zzz.www` is the VIP) and F5.

Inside `sftp` script we would like to know which server we are connecting. Is there any command to show the remote hostname in SFTP?

Comment: Note that conceptually when you perform load balancing it should not matter which back-end server you connect to. (Your HA cluster design should ensure that all back-end servers / pool members remain synchronised.) When it does make difference, consider configuring / using a method to by-pass the load balancing algorithm so you can always connect to any one specific back-end server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sftp` there is no command or call to get the hostname of a connected machine.

However there might be a workaround in case that

- you are not "chrooted" on the sftp server
- you know the OS of the sftp server roughly

Assume that sftp server is running linux then you can get the hostname like e.g.

```
$ echo "get /etc/hostname /tmp/hostname" | sftp my-sftp-server
$ cat /tmp/hostname; rm /tmp/hostname
mysftp.example.domain
```

Comment: Thank you. It's simple trick but really effective.

Answer (score 2):

As I have already commented on your original question on Stack Overflow, SFTP protocol does not have such API. So there cannot be such command, in any SFTP client.

---

If you have a shell access to the server, and you have a SFTP client that can do both shell and SFTP over the same connection (I believe some can do that), then you can use shell `hostname` command (or equivalent for your remote OS).

---

Another thing you can do, is to have the servers display an SSH banner at the beginning of the connection that would identify them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `sftp` command to get the hostname. But you can try one workaround. Open another console and with command:

```
netstat -a|grep :22
```

get the hostname (if you have working DNS resolve) of the host. The problem will be if you have more than one connection on port 22 from the host you work.

If this not work you can do `ssh` to VIP address, get all the IP's and filter VIP. And you will have the IP of current machine.

Comment: I would expect that netstat will show a connection to  the virtual IP-address and you won't see anything that identifies a specific back-end server / pool member

Comment: @HBruijn, it depend of your DNS organization. But yes, this will be VIP address. You can do normal `ssh` to VIP address and then get IPs of this machine. VIa `sftp` you can't